# margin and equal height column problems with flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I made my way to the first attempt on the css3 flex-box. I decided to write a small frame work to play with.

The requirements are quite straight forward - it has to be as minimal as possible, define sizes of boxes and grid while class is only set to parent element. So I came up with something in this fashion

```
[class*="w-all"] {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.row {align-items: flex-start;}
.cols {display:flex; flex: 1 auto}

.w-25, .w-all-25>* {width:25%}
.w-33, .w-all-33>* {width:33.333333333%}
.w-38, .w-all-38>* {width:38.196601125%}
.w-62, .w-all-62>* {width:61.803398875%}
```

and HTML part

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="row cols">
        <section class="w-62 w-all-33">
            <article>
                <h2>header</h2>
                <p>paragraph text</p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <aside class="w-38 w-all-25">
            <article>
                <h2>header</h2>
                <p>paragraph text</p>
            </article>
        </aside>
    </div>
</div>
```

For the most part - it works just fine. Direct children of element with class set to *cols* are main columns and inside those we have grids.

Here's a live example on JSFiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/DGb7k/)

The problem is: main columns aren't equal height (grids are working properly)

Also,  how do I apply margins to elements on the grid? OR I should ask: can I make it different to this (px/em/rem margins are much appreciated)

```
[class*="w-all"] {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
}

.w-all-25>* {width:22%}
.w-all-33>* {width:31.333333333%}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jc5N6/

Answer (score 0):

you misuse the `align-self` rule. I guess you are looking for the `strecth` value , not `flex-start`: http://jsfiddle.net/DGb7k/1/

Comment: Certainly this is closer to what I'm looking for, but not exactly as it stretches the contents of columns to the height of the taller one. For the sake of better visualisation of the problem I set up another fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DGb7k/2/ The goal is to make 'main columns' equal height, but leave grids working flex-start way

Answer (score 0):

Never mind how silly it is to answer your own question...

The fix, as I excepted, was totally simple

```
[class*="w-all"], .cols {display: flex;}
[class*="w-all"] {flex-flow: row wrap;}
```

Here's a Fiddle of a live example http://jsfiddle.net/DGb7k/3/

However margin is still a **live problem**